# Why this code doesn't output anything to label?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridUserAccounts" SkinID="gridviewSkin" PageSize="5">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="User Name" DataField="UserName" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" DataField="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Login Date" SortExpression="LastLoginDate" DataField="LastLoginDate" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Activity Date" SortExpression="LastActivityDate" DataField="LastActivityDate" />
      <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("manage-user-detail.aspx?UserName={0}", Eval("UserName")) %>' ID="linkNavigate" Text="View Detail" />
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind for this is

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    gridUserAccounts.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
    gridUserAccounts.DataBind();
}
```

Now, at 'manage-user-detail.aspx' page i am catching the query string but it doen't work like this

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string userKey1 = Request.QueryString["UserName"];
    Guid UserID = new Guid(Membership.GetUser(userKey1).ProviderUserKey.ToString());
    //Guid userKey = new Guid(userKey1);

    MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(UserID);

    //string userName = mu.UserName;
    lblKey.Text = mu.UserName;
}
```

Nothing is showing up in label. Why?

Comment: Is mu.UserName populated with a value?

Comment: You don't say which event handler your code is in. Which is it?

Comment: Is the username being passed to the next page on the url? Either it is or it isn't in which case you can delete the half that is irrelevant (eg if it is on the url then we don't care where the url came from, if it isn't then clearly that is your problem at the moment so we don't need to worry about what the destination page is trying to do.

Comment: check to make sure that you are passing value in the querystring or else use Bind("UserName") instead of Eval("UserName") for two way binding. Hopefully Bind("UserName") will work

Comment: yes, my code is passing username in url like this; http://localhost:50788/administrator/manage-user-detail.aspx?UserName=admin while at receiving side, i m catching all these (code above) in  page_load() event. And i have tried bind in hyperlink, it gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem with following code

```
 string userName = Membership.GetUser(Request.QueryString["UserName"].ToString()).UserName;
 statusLabel.Text = userName;
```

Answer (score -2):

From my experience the only way to get the querystring is like so:

```
Request.QueryString.Item("UserName");
```

I see that in your code you left out Item.

Comment: Your code is equivalent to his - you can use either method. Thus, it is not the answer to this question.

Comment: Not necessarily so. I've used Request.QueryString without Item and it returned empty. Have you tried it before commenting and rating me down?

Comment: Of course. Request.QueryString is just an instance of NameValueCollection, which implements this indexers to access an item with the specified key. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb.aspx. I would suggest something else was afoot in your own particular scenario when it didn't work.

Comment: It maybe that the thing that was 'afoot' in my scenario is the same thing that's afoot in his.

Comment: Request.QueryString.Item isn't working. My intellisence doesn't recognize the Item property.